# "Page expired" when trying to log in with curl

Tags: php, laravel, curl

I made a little apllication with Laravel and now I want to create a curl script that logs in to automate some testing. I have just this code to log in:

```
<?php


$postData = array(
'name' => 'postmanole',
'password' => 'password'
);


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://a.localhost/login',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_POST => true,
));


$output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $output;

?>
```

But I get "Page expired" view when I run the file.

Im completely new to curl so I don't really know how to take this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this code.

```
$postData = array(
'name' => 'postmanole',
'password' => 'password'
);

$url = 'http://a.localhost/login';

$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
curl_setopt($handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$output = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);

print_r($output);
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
<?php


$postData = array(
'name' => 'postmanole',
'password' => 'password',
'_token' => csrf_token(),
);


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://a.localhost/login',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_POST => true,
));


$output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $output;

?>
```

I hope it would help you.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function csrf_token()

Comment: could you please provide your router and tell me where are you running this piece of code?